# New C++11 range-for (foreach) syntax: which compilers support it?

Tags: c++, for-loop, foreach, c++11

I saw this c++11 code fragment in [this BoostCon presentation by Jeremy Siek](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~siek/boostcon2010bgl.pdf):

```
deque<int> topo_order;
topological_sort(g, front_inserter(topo_order));

for (int v : topo_order){ //line 39
    cout << tasks[v] << endl;
}
```

Upon trying to compile in gcc there is the following error:

```
main.cpp:39: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
```

which then got me wondering, which compilers actually support this syntax?

Comment: Did you check this site? http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: When in doubt, check [Scott Meyers's list](http://www.aristeia.com/C++0x/C++0xFeatureAvailability.htm).  As of November, it looks like the answer is likely  that no one supports this feature entirely yet.

Comment: @ Snowfish and James McNellis, thanks for those links! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, at least GCC [supports it in 4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) (feature is called "Range-based for"). If you already have the latest version, don't forget to add the `-std=c++0x` option.

Comment: I am using the -std=c++0x option, I'll try getting the latest gcc version.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to gcc versions later than version 4.6, both Clang 3.0 and Visual C++ 11 (as of the Visual C++ 11 Beta) both support this C++11 language feature.