# Range For loop help: Expected initializer before ":" token

Tags: c++, c++11

I am completely new to C++ and I am now following the C++ Primer book.

I wrote a small example about strings, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main() {
    string s("Hello World");

    for (auto &c : s)
        c = toupper(c);

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am on Linux with GCC version 4.4.6 and I tried to compile this code with:

```
g++ test_strings.c -std=c++0x
```

but got the following errors:

```
test_strings.c: In function 'int main()':
test_strings.c:14: error: expected initializer before ':' token
test_strings.c:19: error: expected primary-expression before 'return'
test_strings.c:19: error: expected ')' before 'return'
```

I copied the program from the textbook, so I though it was a misspelling but after a check and trying searching on the web and updating my gcc the error reminds. Help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032435/new-c11-range-for-foreach-syntax-which-compilers-support-it Use g++ 4.6

Comment: why does your c++ source file have a C extension?

Comment: … the `.c` extension will cause some compilers to actually misidentify the file's language.

Comment: `g++ foo.c` appears to treat the file as C++ -- but it's definitely poor practice to use the `.c` suffix for a C++ source file.  `.cpp` is most common.  (I've also seen `.C`, but that can cause confusion on case-insensitive file systems.)

Answer (score 5):

As per [the C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), you need to be running gcc 4.6 to get the range-for feature.

The [4.6 changes page](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html) contains:

> Improved experimental support for the upcoming C++0x ISO C++ standard, including support for constexpr (thanks to Gabriel Dos Reis and Jason Merrill), nullptr (thanks to Magnus Fromreide), noexcept, unrestricted unions, **range-based for loops** (thanks to Rodrigo Rivas Costa), opaque enum declarations (thanks also to Rodrigo), implicitly deleted functions and implicit move constructors.

Since you're running gcc 4.4.6, it's not available to you.